# How add TLSA RR in Windows server 2016 DNS zone

Tags: dns, windows-server-2016, dane

I am going to implement DANE protocol on Windows server 2016. I configured  DNS and Active directories. Now I want to generate self signed certificate for my domain and Generate TLSA record. and I want to add TLSA record in DNS.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
Add-DnsServerResourceRecord -TLSA -CertificateAssociationData "digest" -CertificateUsage DomainIssuedCertificate -MatchingType Sha256Hash -Selector FullCertificate -ZoneName mydomain.com -name _443._tcp.example.mydomain.com
```

Also note: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4489468/windows-server-domain-name-system-dns-flag-day-compliance